# Verify Smart Contract ABI Encoded Avalanche

Tags: abi, verify, abiencoderv2

I would like to verify a smart contract with snowtrace.io explorer on Avalanche. For this I need **Constructor Argument ABI-Encoded**

To encode this, I use https://abi.hashex.org/

[image]

Anyway I get the error

```
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
```

How can I fix this?

This is the contract in explorer
https://snowtrace.io/address/0x3160591776e34c319f2ad28ba8c1f4829adc3907

UPDATE

I found out the issue on my site. The actual contract has an internal contructor, so I dont need to provide anything

Thanks the for attention!